# Queue missing from "business queues" view

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm encountering a strange issue on Dynamics CRM 2015, where a queue that I've created is missing from the "Business Queues" view when trying to assign cases to queues. There are 18 queues altogether - 17 of which do show in the "Business Queues" view.

The missing queue appears when I change the view to "Active Queues". I've tried to look at the filters on the "Business Queues" view, but, it is locked down so I can't see how CRM determines what is a business queue and what isn't. I've compared the missing queue to the other queues and can't see any differences at all, either!

Has anyone come across this before? It's very frustrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not well documented by Microsoft, but a Business Queue appears to be defined as a queue that nobody uses as their default queue (i.e. it is then a queue used by the entire business).

This is documented in [CRM Tip of the Day #170: There is no queue like a business queue](http://crmtipoftheday.com/2014/07/04/there-is-no-queue-like-business-queue/):

> If you have a queue that does not show in Business Queues view
>   [...], just find and remove link to
>   it from the teams or users using it as a default. In other words, find
>   users and teams that have field Default Queue linked to the queue in
>   question and set it to null.

Comment: This resolved the issue. I ran a SQL query against the FilteredSystemUser view and found the user that had been assigned the queue as their default. I removed it and now the queue shows in Business Queues again.

Great spot and thanks for the link